# removing a class once a function is called

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular and I am not sure if I can perform this from the html

```
<td ng-class="{'lines-hover': !row.noSpread,
               'line-selected': row.spreadSelected}"></td>
```

I have those classes there, the class that I want to remove is the one named `line-selected` once this function is called

```
<button ng-click="removeAllSlips()">Remove All</button>
```

both belongs to different controllers, all I need is that once I play with that button, that class must be remove, what are your suggestions ?

Comment: simple answer is need to change `row.spreadSelected`. How you do that would depend on if button is within row or not. Need more detail of structure

Comment: sorry, see my update @charlietfl

Comment: can broadcast an event, or can share the `row` data between controllers by using a service. Still not a lot shown for us to work with

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer you can take help from below .http://jsfiddle.net/TahmidTanzim/N9Vqk/

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your exact problem is. Is it that since you have two controllers, trying to affect the first scopes `line-selected` from the second scopes `removeAllSlips()` isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td ng-class="{'lines-hover': !row.noSpread,
               row.spreadSelected?'line-selected':''}"></td>
```

**Controller**

```
function removeAllSlips(){
 $scope.row.spreadSelected = false;
}
```

Try this. Not sure it might affect other rows also.

Comment: no need to change the markup. The way OP markup is, once the variable is no longer truthy, class will be removed

Comment: yes but removeAllSlips is from one controller and ng-class line-selected is from another controller